# RobotC - Simple error from motors not being recognized

Tags: c, move, robotics, nxt, motordriver

We are programming a teleop program for FTC.  Our robot is omni wheeled:

/\
/

At the top we define our four motors as motor_LF, motor_LB, motor_RF, and motor_RB

Unfortunately, on the last few lines that actually move the motors, we get error saying that the motor variables are undefined.

Any help is appreciated.

We are trying robotc for the first time.  We configure it and have the following code:

```
#pragma config(Hubs,  S1, HTMotor,  HTMotor,  HTMotor,  none)
#pragma config(Hubs,  S2, HTServo,  none,     none,     none)
#pragma config(Sensor, S1,     ,               sensorI2CMuxController)
#pragma config(Sensor, S2,     ,               sensorI2CMuxController)
#pragma config(Motor,  motorA,          motorC,        tmotorNXT, PIDControl, encoder)
#pragma config(Motor,  motorB,           ,             tmotorNXT, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  motorC,           ,             tmotorNXT, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  mtr_S1_C1_1,     motor_LF,       tmotorTetrix, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  mtr_S1_C1_2,     motor_LB,       tmotorTetrix, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  mtr_S1_C2_1,     motor_RF,       tmotorTetrix, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  mtr_S1_C2_2,     motor_RB,       tmotorTetrix, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  mtr_S1_C3_1,     motor_L,        tmotorTetrix, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  mtr_S1_C3_2,     motorI,        tmotorTetrix, openLoop)
#pragma config(Servo,  srvo_S2_C1_1,    servo1,               tServoNone)
#pragma config(Servo,  srvo_S2_C1_2,    servo2,               tServoNone)
#pragma config(Servo,  srvo_S2_C1_3,    servo3,               tServoNone)
#pragma config(Servo,  srvo_S2_C1_4,    servo4,               tServoNone)
#pragma config(Servo,  srvo_S2_C1_5,    servo5,               tServoNone)
#pragma config(Servo,  srvo_S2_C1_6,    servo6,               tServoNone)

#include "JoystickDriver.c"                                     //includes code for tele-op

void initializeRobot()                                              //starts the Robot for autonomous
{                                                                                       //starts autonomous

    return;                                                                         //returns the robot to tele-op after autonomous
}                                                                                       //ends autonomous


task main()

{
    //starts tele-op
    initializeRobot();                                                  //starts the robot for teleop



    waitForStart();                                                         //waits for start of tele-op period

    int mThreshold = 15; // To avoid unnecessary movement

    //joystick initialization 
    int xValL, yValL, xValR;

    float scaleFactor = 40.0 / 127; // Sets max. average motor power and maps range
    // of analog stick to this power range

    int motor_LFVal = 0;                                                //sets the initial value of motor_LF to 0
    int motor_LBVal = 0;                                                //sets the initial value of motor_LB to 0
    int motor_RFVal = 0;                                                //sets the initial value of motor_RF to 0
    int motor_RBVal = 0;                                                //sets the initial value of motor_RB to 0

    //repeat forever

    while (true)
    {
        getJoystickSettings(joystick);                      //gets the joystick input throughout match

        xValL = joystick.joy1_x1;
        yValL = joystick.joy1_y1;

        //create threshold for x1 axis
        if(abs(xValL) > mThreshold)         //if the absolute value of joystick 1, left stick, x-axis is greater than the threshold
        {
            xValL = joystick.joy1_x1;                               //robot will move
        }
        else                                                                            //if the absolute value of joystick 1, left stick, x-axis is less than the threshold
        {
            xValL = 0;                                                                  //robot will NOT move
        }

        //create threshold for y1 axis
        if(abs(yValL) > mThreshold)         //if the absolute value of joystick 1, left stick, y-axis is greater than the threshold
        {
            yValL = joystick.joy1_y1;                                   //robot will move
        }
        else                                                                            //if the absolute value of joystick 1, left stick, y-axis is less than the threshold
        {
            yValL = 0;                                                                  //robot will NOT move
        }

        //create threshold for x2 axis
        if(abs(xValR) > mThreshold)         //if the absolute value of joystick 1, right stick, x-axis is greater than the threshold
        {
            xValR = joystick.joy1_x2;                                   //robot will move
        }
        else                                                                            //if the absolute value of joystick 1, right stick, x-axis is less than the threshold
        {
            xValR = 0;                                                                  //robot will NOT move
        }

        //final math and running statements

        //allows each motor to turn independently
        motor[motor_LF] = (-yValL - xValL - xValR) * scaleFactor;  //ERROR HERE                             //-(joy1_y1) - (joy1_x1) - (joy1_x2) = the final value of motor_LF
        motor[motor_LB] = (-yValL + xValL - xValR) * scaleFactor;    //ERROR HERE                           //-(joy1_y1) + (joy1_x1) - (joy1_x2) = the final value of motor_LB
        motor[motor_RF] = (yValL - xValL - xValR) * scaleFactor;     //ERROR HERE                               //(joy1_y1) - (joy1_x1) - (joy1_x2) = the final value of motor_RF
        motor[motor_RB] = (yValL + xValL - xValR) * scaleFactor;     //ERROR HERE                               //(joy1_y1) + (joy1_x1) - (joy1_x2) = the final value of motor_RB


    }

}
```

Comment: will you paste the declaration of motor ?